# USRP: Are RX and TX on the same or different channel for single daughterboard?

Tags: software-defined-radio, software-development, usrp

I've got a USRP X310, currently with just one daughterboard, a WBX-120. I'm writing some C which needs to operate the radio full duplex - I receive on RF A RX2 and transmit on RF A TX/RX.

But I'm confused as to how I identify which number channels I use, because I was under the impression that the function `uhd_usrp_set_tx_subdev_spec` essentially attached my TX path to a particular channel. So if I call `uhd_usrp_set_rx_subdev_spec` and then `uhd_usrp_set_tx_subdev_spec` with `A:0` as the subdevice, am I getting RX on channel 0 and TX on channel 1, or am I getting both on channel 0?

What happens when I add the second daughterboard, to be an SBX-120? In pseudocode I will be calling:

```
uhd_usrp_set_rx_subdev_spec("A:0")
uhd_usrp_set_tx_subdev_spec("A:0")
uhd_usrp_set_rx_subdev_spec("B:0")
uhd_usrp_set_tx_subdev_spec("B:0")
```

Will these then be channels 0, 1, 2, 3? What happens if I change the order of calling `uhd_usrp_set_xx_subdev_spec`?

Comment: which daughterboard type

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for the edit, but OP doesn't mention he's using GNU Radio, and both the usage of the C API and the fact that he's manually setting subdev specs point out that's not the case :) so I removed the [tag:gnuradio] tag!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Whoops. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

The TX channels are separate from the RX channels. Hence, there will be a singkle, dual-stream RX streamer, and a single, dual-stream TX streamer.

The subdev strings in your pseudocode aren't doing what you want; [docs](http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_configuration.html). You also don't need them – if you request a dual-stream streamer, the default behaviour is to count them ascendingly.

So, if you just get two dual-channel RX streams with `uhd_usrp_get_rx_stream`, you just use a `uhd_stream_args_t` that has its `n_channels` field set to `2`. Same for `uhd_usrp_get_tx_stream`.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, but I'm not sure I've explained myself correctly. I did read the page on configuration before posting, but I'm still confused. You are saying that, when referring to either streamer, the WBX will be channel 0 and the SBX channel 1?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me because, when using the `uhd_rx_streamer_recv` function, there is no parameter for the channel. The data coming in on the WBX and on the SBX are completely different. How is this distinguishable?

Comment: _recv will fill two buffers at once when called upon a steamer that was configured for two streams!